# Cycle through each column in a row by name in a table

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a table with seven columns containing dates. Each column has dates that are assigned using a different formula for each column. My ultimate goal is to compare the dates against today, and if it's within a certain amount of time, to fire off an email, and then update the date. My issue, first and foremost is trying to take each row, and run through each of the columns. I've been stabbing in the dark at this  by trying

```
Dim ColWeekly, ColBiWeekly, ColMonthly, ColThMonth, _
ColSxMonth, ColYearly, ColBiYearly As Range
Dim ColVar As Variant
Dim PMTime As Long
Set ColWeekly = Range("PM[Weekly]")   

 For Each Row In [PM].Rows
    For Each Column In [PM].Columns
    Set ColVar = Column.Name
    Select Case ColVar

    Case ColWeekly
        If Date - Cell.Value = 1 Then
        Call Email
        Set Cell.Value = TODAY + 8
        End If
```

But I keep getting a "Type Mismatch error" when it reaches the `Case ColWeekly` line. It doesn't work if I use `Case ColWeekly.name` either. 
I'm sure this is actually a very simple task, but I keep working in circles, so anything you can offer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the row of the headers is static and your dataset is small (given you want to send emails, I'll assume it is) you can usethis kind of check method.
In my example **header**s were in **row 5** and I used the *Like* argument.

```
For i = 6 To LastRow
    For j = 1 To LastColumn
        Select Case True
            Case CStr(Cells(5, j).Value2) Like "*megjegyzés*" 'megjegyzések sortöréseinek eltüntetése
                Cells(i, j).Value = Replace(CStr(Cells(i, j).Value2), vbLf, "")
                Cells(i, j).Value = Replace(CStr(Cells(i, j).Value2), vbCr, "")
                Cells(i, j).Value = Trim(CStr(Cells(i, j).Value2))
            Case CStr(Cells(5, j).Value2) Like "*Tárgy*"
                Cells(i, j).Value = Replace(CStr(Cells(i, j).Value2), vbLf, "")
                Cells(i, j).Value = Replace(CStr(Cells(i, j).Value2), vbCr, "")
                Cells(i, j).Value = Trim(CStr(Cells(i, j).Value2))
            Case CStr(Cells(5, j).Value2) Like "*Kiállítás*" 'dátumok formátumváltása
                Cells(i, j).Value = Year(Cells(i, j).Value) & IIf(Len(Month(Cells(i, j).Value)) = 1, "0" & Month(Cells(i, j).Value), Month(Cells(i, j).Value)) & IIf(Len(Day(Cells(i, j).Value)) = 1, "0" & Day(Cells(i, j).Value), Day(Cells(i, j).Value))
                Cells(i, j).NumberFormat = "General"
            Case CStr(Cells(5, j).Value2) Like "*Esedékes*"
                Cells(i, j).Value = Year(Cells(i, j).Value) & IIf(Len(Month(Cells(i, j).Value)) = 1, "0" & Month(Cells(i, j).Value), Month(Cells(i, j).Value)) & IIf(Len(Day(Cells(i, j).Value)) = 1, "0" & Day(Cells(i, j).Value), Day(Cells(i, j).Value))
                Cells(i, j).NumberFormat = "General"
            Case CStr(Cells(5, j).Value2) Like "*Teljesítés*"
                Cells(i, j).Value = Year(Cells(i, j).Value) & IIf(Len(Month(Cells(i, j).Value)) = 1, "0" & Month(Cells(i, j).Value), Month(Cells(i, j).Value)) & IIf(Len(Day(Cells(i, j).Value)) = 1, "0" & Day(Cells(i, j).Value), Day(Cells(i, j).Value))
                Cells(i, j).NumberFormat = "General"
        End Select
    Next
Next
```

Comment: It's going to be between 100-150 rows, but I hadn't considered this approach. I'm going to give it a try and see how it goes. Thanks! @user3819867

Comment: I ended up using a combination of both of these methods to get the result desired. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your example has a number of issues. I will not be able to correct them without greater detail about the format of your workbook.

Instead I will provide a simple example of how to use `Select Case` correctly and do a simple column comparison. Assign a range name of `Weekly` and `Monthly` to somewhere within columns `A:C` in order to use this example.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub IterateThroughColumns()
    ' Create some variables
    Dim col As Range, colWeekly As Long, colMonthly As Long

    ' Assigns the column number for each range
    colWeekly = Range("Weekly").Column
    colMonthly = Range("Monthly").Column

    For Each col In Sheet1.Range("A:C").Columns
        Select Case col.Column
            Case colWeekly
                MsgBox "Found Weekly range in column " & col.Column
            Case colMonthly
                MsgBox "Found Monthly range in column " & col.Column
            Case Else
                MsgBox "No range was found in column " & col.Column
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

This should give you an idea of how to set up a simple `For Each` loop to iterate through columns, but compare by column number rather than comparing range objects directly.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Does it matter that I have all of this arranged in a table? With header Columns as Weekly, Monthly, etc? @grovesNL

Comment: If it is a named range (which is one column wide) then no, it does not matter.